# « il fut colporter la nouvelle » : grammaire (Messieurs les Ronds-de-Cuir, Georges Courteline)

Tags: grammaire, sens, verbes

> — Plus un mot ! Sortez, vous dis-je ; allons, oust ! hors d’ici ! quittez ce
> lieu que vous déshonorez de votre ignoble présence !
> Le chef, éperdu, obéit. Sur son importance prudhommesque de tout à
> l’heure, ce coup de théâtre inattendu avait opéré instantanément, à la
> manière d’un acide sur la teinture de tournesol. Jusqu’au soir, de bureau
> en bureau, il fut colporter la nouvelle :
> — Je vous demande pardon, je vous dérange, mais ce qui vient de
> m’arriver est tellement extraordinaire…

J'ai vérifié que le bout de phrase « il fut colporter la nouvelle » est le même sur deux éditions.

un texte du domaine public.bibebook [www.bibebook.com](http://www.bibebook.com)

E. Flammarion

Je ne comprend pas cette forme sans que l'infinitif soit remplacé par un participe passé, et « il » serait le pronom impersonnel. Le sens pourrait-il être celui de « il fut à colporter la nouvelle » ? (« il » serait alors le pronom personnel  remplaçant « Le chef »). « Être + inf » ne se trouve pas au TLFi. Autrement,  s'agirait-il d'une erreur qui persiste dans plusieurs éditions ?

Comment: Tu as répondu toi-même à [une question similaire](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/44082/il-sen-fut-vs-il-sen-va) il n'y a pas si longtemps.

Comment: Chercher « Souvent sans expression du lieu, suivi d'un inf. » au TLFi à _être_.

Answer (score 2):

Il ne s'agit pas d'une erreur. Au passé simple, le verbe ***être*** peut parfois remplacer le verbe ***aller*** dans un registre littéraire.

> *Dès qu'il aperçut une femme, **il fut se cacher** sous une touffe de roseaux.*
> Bernardin de Saint-Pierre, *Études de la nature*, 1784.

Le sens est donc ici :

> *Il **alla** colporter la nouvelle.*

Cette [substitution du verbe ***aller*** par le verbe ***être***](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8245/quest-ce-qui-est-le-plus-commun-jai-%C3%A9t%C3%A9-%C3%A0-paris-ou-je-suis-all%C3%A9-%C3%A0-paris) se rencontre aussi souvent au passé composé dans un registre cette fois-ci courant :

> *Il **a été** colporter la nouvelle* pour *Il **est allé** colporter la nouvelle.*

<sub>Note: En espagnol, les passé simples des verbes aller (*ir*) et être (*ser*) sont identiques : *fui, fuiste, fue, fuimos, fuisteis, fueron.*</sub>

Comment: Cette conjugaison en espagnol m'a rappelé le latin. Je me demande si la même chose était possible en latin, c'est-à-dire si _sum, es, esse_ pouvait être utilisé pour _eo, is, ire_ - en latin, les conjugaisons pour ces deux verbes sont disjointes à tous les temps, si je ne me trompe.

Comment: @Frank Il y a une logique là dessous. Aller quelque part implique qu'on sera (verbe être) à ce quelque part une fois le trajet achevé. Les verbes être et aller sont aussi parmi les plus irréguliers en français comme en espagnol car ils sont historiquement construits à partir de plusieurs verbes différents.